# setInterval creates new object

Tags: javascript, class, prototype

I am writing a small application in JavaScript and I have a class and a prototype method.

```
function Canvas(_canvasId, _page) {
    this.c = document.getElementById(_canvasId);
    this.ctx = this.c.getContext("2d");
    this.page = _page;
};

Canvas.prototype.draw = function () {
    console.log(this);

    switch (this.page) {
        case "_CitySystem":
            //this.renderCitySystem();
            break;
    }
};
```

I then create a new instance and call the draw method:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var g = new Canvas("cCity", "_CitySystem");
    setInterval(g.draw, 1000);
});
```

The problem I am having is that when I do

```
console.log(this);
```

I was expecting it to output the Canvas object properties, instead I get the windows object properties:

[image]

However is I do

```
d.draw();
```

Without the setInterval, the console output is what I expect it to be, so in the callback in setInterval, the end result is a different object, how can I tell setInterval that I want to use the object properties of what I have passed in?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `g.draw` with `function () { g.draw(); }`.

Comment: `g.draw.bind(g)` also works

Comment: Just has some redundancy.

Answer (score -2):

When you call [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) or [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout), you're really calling it against the `window`.

You need to pass context, which can be done with jQuery.proxy:

```
setInterval($.proxy(g.draw, g), 1000);
```

See documentation at: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/